# Lowering down time stamping for live video

Tags: video, timestamp, gstreamer, pipeline, lag

I am trying to lower down timestamping problem with my live feed from 2 usb camers.
I am running this code on the terminal but there is lot of lag from the video feed:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! videobox left=-320 border-alpha=0 ! queue ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240 ! videobox left=1 ! queue ! mix.
```

I know instead of using `x-raw-yuv` I can use something else but I am not sure what should I use, plus using framerate like 25/1 would help but I am not sure where I need to put it, I did this but I am getting error of stopping pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240, framerate 25/1 ! videobox left=-320 border-alpha=0 ! queue ! videomixer name=mix ! ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240, framerate 25/1 ! videobox left=1 ! queue ! mix.
```

Comment: What does "lower down timestamping" mean?

Comment: its video lag.. basically my video is lagging and timestamping error coming up..

Comment: What is lag? is it Buffering? latency? AV sync?